# Concatener campos de un subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Tengo la siguiente consulta en sql sever 2014

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMPTABLE
(
    ID       INT,
    DATACOLUM    VARCHAR(5)
)
INSERT INTO #TEMPTABLE VALUES 
(1,'A'),(1,'B'),(1,'C'),(2,'D'),(3,'E'),(4,'F')

SELECT 
    TB.ID,
    STUFF((SELECT ',' + DATACOLUM FROM TB  FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'') AS CONCATSTUFF
FROM(
SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTABLE) AS TB
GROUP BY TB.ID
```

el resultado esperado es que pueda concatenar la columna "DATACOLUM" que se obtiene de la sub consulta

```
SELECT *
FROM #TEMPTABLE) AS TB
```

la sub consulta es solo un ejemplo ya que se espera tener una sub consulta mas compleja

Comment: Qué motor de base de datos y versión estás usando?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás bastante cerca, la consulta para la concatenación sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT  t.Id, 
        ConcatStuff = STUFF((SELECT ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), DATACOLUM) 
                             FROM #TEMPTABLE 
                             WHERE ID = t.ID
                             FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
FROM #TEMPTABLE AS t
GROUP BY t.Id;
```

El resultado es:

```
╔════╦═════════════╗
║ Id ║ ConcatStuff ║
╠════╬═════════════╣
║  1 ║ A,B,C       ║
║  2 ║ D           ║
║  3 ║ E           ║
║  4 ║ F           ║
╚════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: en la consulta que me conmentas el stuff lo esta aplicando directamente a la tabla #TEMPTABLE pero el stuff que comento lo debe aplicar a una sub consulta no a la tabla #TEMPTABLE

Comment: @DEVJ No entiendo bien tu comentario, pero para concatenar tus datos debes usar la consulta que posteé. Si es necesario puedes usar **toda** esa consulta como una "tabla derivada" o una CTE